# Remote configuration of PCs

Tags: linux, window, raspberry-pi

My organisation is about to deploy 500+ Raspberry Pi's(running Debian) across the country. I have been given the task of configuring these devices. Configuration depends on specific installation, so cannot be configured before installation and the staff at the remote site seriously lack skills. BTW These remote sites are all over Southern Africa.

Each of these remote sites will be connecting these Raspberry Pis(RPi) to a Windows server which will be on an Intranet(No internet access).

I think that I need a program, probably running on the aforementioned server, to make the configuration of the RPis as fool proof as possible so that the remote staff may do the configuration that cannot be automated.

My background is Linux(so the RPi's are not an issue), languages include C, C++, HTML and PHP. Not much Windows.

My initial thought on program development is HTML but connecting to each RPi without knowing its IP would be a challenge. On Linux I could do something with ntop but how to do this on Windows?

All suggestions on how I should proceed are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol). This way each RPi would announce itself like ordinary UPnP devices, so that Windows user can click on the newly appeared device and would get to its web interface. Or your server software would discover the devices via SSDP and initiate a configuration session.

Comment: After a bit of Googling of SSDP this sounds interesting. Have you implemented something similar to what I need? If so please let me look at your code.

Comment: I don't have the code, but I have used such implementation on a 32-bit ARM micro controller.